# Como detectar cuando se llega a la parte inferior de un NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, nestedscrollview, bottom

**Descripción:**

Estoy usando este listener en uno de mis proyectos para verificar cuándo los usuarios llegan al final de NestedScroll y está funcionando perfectamente.

**Problema:**

Estoy tratando de usar este mismo listener en otro proyecto y no funciona :(

**Debug:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Explicación del proceso de debug:**

Una vez que abro mi actividad, el primer punto de interrupción se activa pero el cuerpo del método no responde. Una vez que presiono f9 (Reanudar programa), el proceso de depuración se detiene y la aplicación comienza a ejecutarse y el recycler se llena con mi API

**¿Qué quiero?**

Necesito que este listener verifique cuando el usuario se desliza hacia la parte inferior (cuando llegan a la última publicación) para mostrar más elementos (paginación del recycler) pero no puedo porque el listener no responde (ver el rectángulo verde en la foto de arriba)

**Código xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/nested"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twentydp"
       ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txt_resultados_lore"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twentydp"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
       android:text="@string/resultados_lore"
       android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
       android:textSize="@dimen/thirteensp"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"/>

   <View
       android:id="@+id/view_barra1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/twodp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tendp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tendp"
       android:background="@color/light_gray2"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_resultados_lore"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_animales_filtrados"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fivedp"
       tools:listitem="@layout/item_row_recycler_filtered_animals"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_barra1" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Código java del Listener:**

```
binding.nested.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {
p.showToast(getActivity(),"test-text");
if(scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()){
    page++;
    binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
```

Como mencioné anteriormente... el toast nunca se muestra cuando me deslizo porque el listener no responde en este proyecto, pero está respondiendo 100% bien en otro proyecto.

**Gracias por leer!**

**Edit:**

También probé con el listener del recycler y funciona (el listener), pero el if que comprueba si el usuario llegó al final no funciona ( ¿tal vez tengo un problema de diseño xml? No sé... :(  )

```
binding.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
    //Se activa cada vez que deslizo (y no cuando alcanzo el bottom)
}

//Otra forma de chequear si se alcanzó la parte inferior
if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        //Se activa cada vez que deslizo (y no cuando alcanzo el bottom)
        
    }
//Otra forma de chequear si se alcanzó la parte inferior
int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    int pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
        //Se activa cada vez que deslizo (y no cuando alcanzo el bottom)
    }
}
});
```